# How can I get multiple repositories in Visual Studio Code in the same instance?

Tags: visual-studio-code

OS: [macOS v10.12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Sierra) (Sierra)

Before the latest update November 2016, v1.8, I was able to open new windows in the same instance of Visual Studio Code. Meaning I can have my API repository and my website repository open and tabbed at the top. Which was great, because it made it very easy to switch repositories without remembering where windows were.

It seems this functionality was removed in this newest release. I checked through the release notes, but I couldn't find a way to re-enable this feature that I enjoyed.

How can I re-enable this view?

Comment: Updated ticket to follow for Progress on this bug: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/15478

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm on the Visual Studio Code team. There is no way as of version 1.8 to enable this feature again, but we are tracking the work here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/17199

We're currently coordinating with Electron to get proper native support for tabs on Macs.

Comment: Thanks for the info